# C++ Preprocessor Macros with relation to Include files

Tags: c++, macros, include, c-preprocessor

I was just wondering whether the C++ preprocessor is capable of macros such as:

```
#define include<a> include<a.h>
```

Which would convert

```
#include<stdio>
```

into

```
#include<stdio.h>
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: The accepted answer to the duplicate question isn't all that helpful.  A number of the other answers are more helpful.  The key point is that even if the output of macro processing looks like a preprocessor directive, it is _not_ a preprocessor directive.  So you can't generate the `#include` part of the line from a macro.  You can, however, generate the file name part of the `#include` line as a macro.  You just have to be a bit careful, that's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `#include` directives can't be replaced directly with a macro. However, the entity to be included can be the result of a macro expansion. That is, if you need to use different header names, you can define a macro which expands to what is being included, e.g.:

```
#define CONCAT(a,b) a ## b
#ifdef USE_C_NAMES
#   define MAKE_NAME(x) <x.h>
#else
#    define MAKE_NAME(x) <CONCAT(c,x)>
#endif
#include MAKE_NAME(stdio)
```